# Unmarshalling XML element with Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm working on a restful client. I've this xml tag from the restful webservice:

```
<ProductRegistration pf:urn="urn:nipf:product-registration:IB:NIC:9472693" pf:url="http://immix-dev.natinst.com/cpr-rest/1/en/product-registration/IB:NIC:9472693.xml?dataset=full" pf:locale="en">
```

....

This element contains several things I need to store. I have this java object to store the tag and all the information I need.

```
@XmlRootElement(name ="ProductRegistration")
public class ProductRegistration {

    private ProductItem productItem;    
    private InstalledProduct installedProduct;

    @XmlElement(name = "productItem")
    public ProductItem getProductItem() {
        return productItem;
    }
    public void setProductItem(ProductItem productItem) {
        this.productItem = productItem;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "installedProduct")
    public InstalledProduct getInstalledProduct() {
        return installedProduct;
    }
    public void setInstalledProduct(InstalledProduct installedProduct) {
        this.installedProduct = installedProduct;
    }
}
```

And I'm doing the connection like this:

```
public Collection<ProductRegistration> get(String url){
        GenericType<Collection<ProductRegistration>> productRegistrationType = new GenericType<Collection<ProductRegistration>>(){};

        WebResource webResource = getWebResource(url);      

        return webResource.get(productRegistrationType);
}
```

It sends a collection because the WS returns a list of productRegistration objects. But when I try to store the WS's result in the Java object, I get a "Bad Request" error. Any ideas?
--EDIT--

The envelope looks like this:

```
<ProductRegistrations xmlns:pdi="http://www.mywebpage.com/schemas/provider-framework/pdi/2" xmlns:contact="http://www.mywebpage.com/schemas/provider-framework/contact/1" xmlns:pf="http://www.mywebpage.com/schemas/provider-framework/1/providers" xmlns:ib="http://www.mywebpage.com/schemas/provider-framework/ib/2" xmlns="http://www.mywebpage.com/schemas/provider-framework/cpr/1" xmlns:tca="http://www.mywebpage.com/schemas/provider-framework/tca/1" xmlns:up="http://www.mywebpage.com/schemas/provider-framework/up/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" pf:url="http://immix-dev.mywebpage.com/cpr-rest/1/en/product-registration/byContact.xml?contactRepresentation=urn:nipf:up-contact-address:2061817&dataset=full" retrieved="true" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mywebpage.com/schemas/provider-framework/cpr/1 http://immix-dev.mywebpage.com/cpr-rest/1/meta/schema.xsd">
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a namespace Annotation to your ProductRegistration class:

```
@XmlType(namespace="..wherever pf comes from..")
```

Comment: Something like this?
@XmlRootElement(name ="ProductRegistration")
@XmlType(namespace = "http://www.mywebpage.com/schemas/provider-framework/pdi/2")

public class ProductRegistration {
....